# How to become immortal in Western world in compare to Chinese legends and western mythology?

Tags: greek, mythohistory, chinese, immortality

I saw some Chinese series where were immortal people. Question is if someone knows the path how to be immortal in nowadays. Because the 1000 years Kingdom is closer and closer and it seems there is a possibility to reach immortality in nowadays too. From my point of view what I've got it is not a "real" immortality, not eternal, just for couple of 100s years, "only" maybe to 500 or 1000. Of course I understand it is related to 3 Nadis (Ida, Pingala, Sushumna) and there are some Chinese legends about it but I did not imagine it would be possible in Western world until not happened that I've got 3... Sorry, I cannot write it down publicly but maybe someone has similar or better information and understanding of this. I could not imagine sooner it would be possible before 1000 years Kingdom...

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to actually obtain immortality, or are you looking, as Mary gracious assumed, about mythological ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Greco-Roman mythos, the way to become immortal was to eat [ambrosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrosia), the food of the gods.  Alas, the only real way for humans to obtain it was to undergo apotheosis and become a god.

In Norse mythos, the way is to eat the apples of [Idun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C3%B0unn).  This appears not to be feasible for humans.

In Christian times, the chief belief was in alchemy.  The [Philosopher's Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher%27s_stone) could be used to make an elixir of immortality, as well as turn ordinary metals into gold (which does not tarnish, rust, or corrode, and so is immortal).